# Enabling MFA in Sagemaker Studio Lab

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

Is there any way to enable Multi Factor Authentication in AWS Sagemaker Studio Lab?
I want to use my private data to analyze and run ML algorithms. How secure is Sagemaker Studio Lab? Is there any way to make it more secure? Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker Studio Lab is a *separate* service from AWS, provided free of charge much like Google Colab. You have almost no options regarding authentication and customisation.

If you’re looking for a more secure and customisable ML platform, [SageMaker Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/studio/) is almost identical, and you can configure access for you (and your team) via [AWS IAM Identity Center](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/identity-center/), which would allow you to enforce MFA.